# Displaying a flood map with Python

Tags: python, tiff

I would like to create a flood map based on this data: https://data.jrc.ec.europa.eu/dataset/jrc-floods-floodmapeu_rp10y-tif/resource/0a0c7945-94ad-4f5b-9c97-9120166a83a8. The Zip File contains tif, ovr, XML and tfw files.

As I am relatively new to Python, I have not been successful so far. First, I set my working directory where I had my data. Thereafter, I tried to define a relative path to the file and to open it with this:

```py
# Open lidar dem
lidar_dem_xr = rxr.open_rasterio(lidar_dem_path, masked=True).squeeze()

lidar_dem_xr
```

However, I always get this:

> MemoryError: Unable to allocate 21.6 GiB for an array with shape (1, 45242, 63976) and data type float64.

So far, I could not come up with an idea. If someone has an idea how to approach this, I would be very thankful.

Comment: I think you might want to add more detail - what is rxr imported as? Perhaps there is another tag this needs?

Comment: Your code would work, if you had enough memory (RAM). The error message tells you that the object you try to load would take 21.6 GB of RAM, which you don't have.

Comment: You could try using the `dask` library and the `chunks` parameter of `rioxarray.open_rasterio` to read the data in chunks instead of all at once. Or you find a smaller dataset which does not cause such memory problems first, to get familiar with the general approaches, before coming back to this large dataset and deal with the memory issues.